# How to create Polly's policy for several WCF Clients

Tags: c#, wcf, dry, polly

There is a 3rd-party service I need to integrate with. It has 3 endpoints for 3 calls. That's it, each API call has its own endpoint with its own wsdl. So there isn't any connection (like inheritance) between POCOs of different calls. BUT results of these calls are very similar. Particularly every result has 'Errors' property that contains errors in a pipe-delimited string. Some errors are shared among calls (have the same name) and have to be handled in a similar manner.

My goal is to retry calls when either an exception was raised or there is an error named 'EXCEPTION' in Errors. I'm trying to use Polly to reach this goal. The only way I see now is to create separate Policy for each call. Is there any way to create a single policy for all calls?

Sample code is below (in real project *Result classes and *Service interfaces are autogenerated by VisualStudio when importing wsdl):

```
public partial class CreateResult
{
    public string Errors {get;set;} 
}

public interface ICreateService
{
    Task<CreateResult> CreateAsync();
}

public partial class UpdateResult
{
    public string Errors {get;set;} 
}

public interface IUpdateService
{
    Task<UpdateResult> UpdateAsync();
}

public partial class DeleteResult
{
    public string Errors {get;set;} 
}

public interface IDeleteService
{
    Task<DeleteResult> DeleteAsync();
}

public class Connector
{
    private readonly ICreateService _createService;
    private readonly IUpdateService _updateService;
    private readonly IDeleteService _deleteService;
    private readonly Policy _policy = ???; 

    public Connector(ICreateService createService, IUpdateService updateService, IDeleteService deleteService)
    {
        _createService = createService;
        _updateService = updateService;
        _deleteService = deleteService;
    }

    public async Task<CreateResult> CreateAsync()
    {
        // sample policy: var policy = Policy.Handle<Exception>()
        //                                   .OrResult<CreateResult>(r => r.Errors.Contains("EXCEPTION"))
        //                                   .Retry();
        // Now I need to create such a policy for every call. How can I create a single policy or a factory method to enforce DRY principle?

        return _policy.ExecuteAsync(() => _createService.CreateAsync());
    }

    public async Task<UpdateAsync> UpdateAsync()
    {
        return _policy.ExecuteAsync(() => _updateService.UpdateAsync());
    }

    public async Task<DeleteResult> DeleteAsync()
    {
        return _policy.ExecuteAsync(() => _deleteService.DeleteAsync());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share some sample code , as I need to build a POLLY SOAP Client for consuming WSDL webservices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that each return type has a property containing a collection of `Error` objects you can eliminate some code duplication by having each policy reuse the method that inspects that collection.

For example:

```
public static class PolicyExtensions
{
    public static bool ContainsExceptionMessage(this IEnumerable<Error> errors)
    {
        return errors.Any(error => error.Name.Contains("EXCEPTION"));
    }
}
```

You'll need multiple policies but each can reuse this method:

```
var policy = Policy.HandleResult<MyResultClass>(
    result => result.Errors.ContainsExceptionMessage())
        .Or<Exception>()
        .Retry();
```

If each of your classes implements an interface indicating that it contains a collection of errors, you can also create a generic function to return a policy:

```
public interface IHasErrors
{
    List<Error> Errors { get; }
}

Policy<THasErrors> CreateExceptionPolicy<THasErrors>() where THasErrors:IHasErrors
{
    return Policy.HandleResult<THasErrors>(
            result => result.Errors.ContainsExceptionMessage())
        .Or<Exception>()
        .Retry();
}
```

Now you're still creating multiple policies, but they're much easier to create, and none of their code is duplicated.

```
var policy = CreateExceptionPolicy<UpdateResult>();
```